# How do you find the window size/response time of a kiln?

Tags: arduino, relayjs, pid-controller, control-theory, kiln

I am using this [libray]((https://github.com/imax9000/Arduino-PID-Library/blob/master/examples/PID_RelayOutput/PID_RelayOutput.ino)for my PID controller and I just don't understand how to find the window time for my system.

Extra info that may help: Looking at the data sheet found [here](https://download.datasheets.com/pdfs/2016/11/6/12/8/22/185/fotek_/manual/2013515_90632265.pdf) for my relay it says the response time is 8.3ms at 60hz. Should I make my response time that for my kiln? Or is this bad thinking.My kiln is a quartz tube wound in 130watts worth of kanthal wire in a blanket of rockwool.

Could I find this by just turning on my kiln for 2 seconds then back off and wait to see how long it takes for it to settle at the new higher temperature? Because it takes 40 seconds to do that. Is the time it takes the window size/ response time of my kiln? Or should is their another way to find the window size/ response time of a PID system?

I've already considered using a off and on for it and decided against it and would really prefer to use a PID since the fluctuations in temperature would be bad for my experiments. Thanks for any help in advanced.